# Svg Images not showing on screen in React js using Import and images

Tags: reactjs, svg

the SVG images that I already imported are not showing on the screen, and in the console show them as a /static/media/svg-1.....svg

[image: See the Image]

the code I wrote
[image: See the Image]

Comment: You need an `img` element to show images. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img . Adding `src` to a `div` element won't do anything.

Comment: You are right! cuz I'm using styled Components I didn't pay attention to it. So i changed the DIV to IMG tag. Thanks mate